# jQuery Datatables and sparse data from server

Tags: jquery, mongodb, datatables

I have a datatables with several columns like name, email, phone etc. But the data from the server side comes from mongo and some of the users do not phone so the response JSON does not contain phone field.

Datatables doesn't seem to handle cases like this? Is there any other way than create empty fields manually?

Answer (score 0):

You add field to the collection if it is not exist as follows :

```
> db.myCollection.update({"phone":{$exists:false}},{$set:{"phone":""}},false,true);
```

Comment: I might have control over existing data and I don't really want to start defining schema for MongoDB...